# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 _OBJC_CLASS_$_ALApplicationList theos

Tags: ios, makefile, jailbreak, cydia, theos

I am trying to use [AppList](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AppList) by **rpetrich** to display applications' list dynamically. But I am getting following error while compiling;

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALApplicationList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Settings.mm.9ffba1be.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I think I have placed all required header files and library at correct place as mentioned in the link i.e. **Header files** in *theos include folder* and **libapplist.dylib** in *theos' lib folder*. Here is my makefile:

**MakeFile:**

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

BUNDLE_NAME = Settings
Settings_FILES = Settings.mm
Settings_INSTALL_PATH = /Library/PreferenceBundles
Settings_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
Settings_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = Preferences
Settings_LIBRARIES = applist
Settings_LDFLAGS = -lapplist

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/bundle.mk

internal-stage::
    $(ECHO_NOTHING)mkdir -p $(THEOS_STAGING_DIR)/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences$(ECHO_END)
    $(ECHO_NOTHING)cp entry.plist $(THEOS_STAGING_DIR)/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences/Settings.plist$(ECHO_END)
```

**Settings.mm**

```
#import <Preferences/Preferences.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AppList/ALApplicationList.h> //no error here. compiles fine

@interface SettingsListController: PSListController {
}
@end

@implementation SettingsListController
- (id)specifiers {
    if(_specifiers == nil) {
        _specifiers = [[self loadSpecifiersFromPlistName:@"Settings" target:self] retain];
    }
    return _specifiers;
}
@end

@interface ApplicationsList : PSListController
{
    BOOL found;
}

@end

@implementation ApplicationsList

- (id)specifiers {
    if(_specifiers == nil) {


        NSMutableArray *__specifiers = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] retain];

           ALApplicationList *apps = [ALApplicationList sharedApplicationList]; //list all the apps

         NSArray *displayIdentifiers = [[apps.applications allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
         return [[apps.applications objectForKey:obj1] caseInsensitiveCompare:[apps.applications objectForKey:obj2]];}]; //sort the apps by display name
        // [displayIdentifiers retain]; //make sure it doesn't disappear when you actually need to use it, if you only use it once, release it

        if(displayIdentifiers.count > 0)
        {
            UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Wow!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [myAlert show];
            [myAlert release];

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < displayIdentifiers.count; i++) {
            PSSpecifier* specifier = [PSSpecifier preferenceSpecifierNamed:[displayIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]
                                                                    target:self
                                                                       set:NULL
                                                                       get:NULL
                                                                    detail:Nil
                                                                      cell:PSSwitchCell
                                                                      edit:Nil];


            [specifier setProperty:bundle forKey:@"lazy-bundle"];
            specifier->action = @selector(lazyLoadBundle:);
            [__specifiers addObject:specifier];
            }
            [specifier release];
        }
        _specifiers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:__specifiers];

    }
    return _specifiers;
}

@end
```

Please tell me what am I missing? I am really unable to figure out this issue. Thanks alot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357311/linker-error-undefined-symbols-symbols-not-found

Comment: @iPatel thanks for the link. But where am I suppose to do that in makefile?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry it has been years. Don't remember how I solved :(